# Re-use function on every UIVIewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a function that use very common on every UIViewController

```
func backPreviousScreen() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Is anyway that I don't have to write detail that function above on each UIViewController ?, just need some method like I can inherit it, and use it in all UIViewController ?

Comment: That's not how you decide to move stuff into functions because you repeat yourself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a protocol and add extension to it:

```
protocol Dismissable  {
}

extension Dismissable  where Self: UIViewController  {
    func backPreviousScreen() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

Now just mark the view controller class with this protocol and you are ready to go:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, Dismissable  {

}
```

Comment: I would prefer a protocol name ending with the `able` suffix, but anyway this is the most readable answer

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti yes you are right I don't like the name either. I just could't make the better one, even  Previousable doesn't sound good for me :)

Comment: @Greg: In this case,  Is it possible to attach function on protocol Dismissable to button 's action from MyViewController ?

Comment: @VoKimNguyen This function doesn't accept any parameter (like sender, button, slider, etc) so I would advice to create a function which will fire when the button is pressed and call this method inside it.

Comment: @Greg: Thank you, but if that function have parameter, is any way to add it to button 's action on MyViewController ? Something like
    btnBack.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.backToPreviousScreen(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

Comment: I don't think so. To use the function as a selector it should be marked as @objc but you cannot mark extension with this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Create a BaseViewController with the method in it, then all of your viewcontrollers can inherit from it, thus all having the function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of create base class method, Create a `UINavigationController` Extension. Which is you can use any where in your application.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension UINavigationController
{
    func backPreviousScreen (){
        self.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

Use as follow `self.navigationController.backPreviousScreen()`

Comment: When passing boolean is so hard that we need extension for this

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using a protocol is good, but i would recommend you to just create a class called BaseViewController that extends UIViewController like this

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
-(void) backPreviousScreen;
```

Then you can use it in any other controller like this

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"
@interface LoginViewController : BaseViewController
```

This was you can put functions, objects and everything you want and just call

```
[super backPreviousScreen];
```

from any of your subclasses

I recommend using this method and not the protocol because this way you can even create outlets easily since the storyboard and nibs recognise the base class and let you to create outlets that you can later access as well using

```
[super.someTextField setText:@"Some Text"];
```